# Linux two processes to read from standard input (osmosis osm)

Tags: linux, openstreetmap, stdin, osmosis

I need to decompress a very large file (100GB+) and get it be processed by two parallel threads. Problem is that I want to feed uncompressed content to both threads at the same time using STDIN/STDOUT

```
bzip2 north-america-latest.osm.bz2 |  \
osmosis --read-xml file=- \ # get first thread
--tf accept-ways highway=motorway
outPipe.0=motorway \
--fast-read-xml file=- # here another thread
--tf accept-nodes place=\*
outPipe.0=places \
--merge inPipe.0=motorway inPipe.1=places
```

Syntax might be not so transparent but idea is that both threads read from the same standard input and basically steal each other data.

Somehow I need to get each thread its own STDIN (or another temp in-memory stream) and split output of bzip2 between them.

Comment: If you are worried about speed then try to take a look at [osmium-tool](https://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/).

Comment: eventually the solution was to abandon osmosis tool as it is written in Java (thus slow) and switch to a combination of osmconvert/osmfilter tools. Both tools written in c++ and provide about 10 times better performance than osmosis. In particular osmconvert can do bounding box filtering, and osmfilter can help to cherry pick elements from the stream of osm data. Osm filter is not easy to configure and documentation could be written with more examples but once configured right, it works very good.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tee to split output to multiple processes

```
bzip2 north-america-latest.osm.bz2 | tee >(command1) | command2
```

You can have as many commands as you want.

```
bzip2 north-america-latest.osm.bz2 | tee >(command1) >(command2) >(command3) | command4
```

The command after the pipe is optional. If omitted it will continue to go to stdout.

Comment: it is not that simple. It should be one command that can have two fake stdins. I will probably remove this question as I found feedback from developer of this Open Street Map tool who said it is not possible to do. Solution was to first create a smaller uncompressed file with preprocessed data and than let each process to read it directly. They can read the same file but could not share stdin.